# Failure in build on Azure Devops

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

We have a multi-module Spring project which has 3 modules in total.
One parent pom.xml and two child pom.xml .

The build is compiling fine on the local machine while it is failing on the Azure DevOps.

The error is as follows :-

**Non resolvable parent pom for xxxxx(project specific) : Could not transfer artifact XXXXX from/to XXXXX: authentication failed for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXXXXX , status : 401 Unauthorized and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM.**

Things that I have tried :

1. Replacing the existing pom.xml with pom.xml of the production ( no significant changes ).
2. Exclusively specifying the relative paths for parent pom.xml in child pom.xml

Nothing seems to be working on DevOps though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Docker task to build your application?

If so, I had the exact same problem, and I fixed it by copying the settings.xml to the root of the build container.

```
COPY settings.xml /root/.m2/
```

I'm also using the Maven Authenticate task, which is responsible for generating the proper settings.xml file.